# Frequently Used metadata Hashmap

Tags: java, caching, hashtable

Are there any implementations of a static size hashtable that limits the entries to either the most recently or most frequently used metadata? I would prefer not to keep track of this information myself.

I know most caching components keep track of this, but I would rather not introduce quite a lot of new dependencies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can build an LRU cache using the standard JDK library using [`LinkedHashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html):

```
public class MyLRUCache<K, V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> {

    private final int maxEntries;

    public MyLRUCache(int maxEntries) {
        // you can be a bit fancy with capacity and load factor
        super(16, 0.75, true);
        this.maxEntries = maxEntries;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> eldest) {
        return size() > maxEntries;
    }
}
```

You may want to play with [`WeakReference`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html)s as well.

Comment: I like that. I haven't heard of that before.

Comment: Wish I knew about WeakReferences before. That would make this cache mechanism a bit more awesome when I was working on it.

Answer (score 2):

Use [LinkedHashMap](http://java.sun.com/j2se/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) and override [removeEldestEntry](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry(java.util.Map.Entry)) and make sure to use the 
[constructor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#LinkedHashMap(int,%20float,%20boolean)) that allows to `accessOrder as true`

Accessordered makes the map remove the least recently accessed item instead of the eldest.

All queries will alter the structure of the map, hence be a tiny bit slower.

Example:

```
public AccesOrderedLRUCache<V,K> extends LinkedHashMap<V,K>{
    private final m_capacity;

    public AccesOrderedLRUCache(int capacity) {
        super(0.75*capacity, 0.75, true);
        m_capacity = capacity;
    }

    @Override 
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry (Map.Entry<K,V> eldest) {
         return size() > getCapacity(); 
    }

    public int getCapacity() {
        return m_capacity;
    }
}
```

Comment: not in jdk 1.6.0_13. http://kickjava.com/src/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java.htm (dont know which version that is, but still no)

Comment: @Fedearne, thanks.  I confused access-ordered by insertion-ordered

Comment: 0.75*capacity is probably not what you mean here.  Assuming you actually mean capacity/0.75 ?

Also getCapacity is missing a parens and I would prefer ref'ing m_capacity to LRUCache.this.cacheSize in removeEldestEntry().

Comment: @Alex You are totally right about the cacheSize being wrong. 0.75*capacity is (as You most likely already know) the initial capacity. I don't se any point in making it larger than the maximum size. 75% of the maximum capacity might be that clever either. Do You have some insights on that?